# Rotate osmdroid map around arbitrary point

Tags: android, osmdroid

I need to rotate my map around current location marker. Current location marker will be placed at the boottom of map. Like on a picture. [Map with location marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaT5L.png)

Comment: Please explain your requirements. Are you need some kind of a static map?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for response. I already found solution myself, but may be it's worst variant :)  It would be awesome if you can improve this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my task with this code:

```
//rotate map
map.setMapOrientation(angle);

//center to current location
GeoPoint point = mMyLocationNewOverlay.getMyLocation();
if (point == null) return;
mapController.setCenter(point);

//calculate translation
float bottomPadding = map.getHeight() * 0.1f;
float radius = map.getHeight()/2 - bottomPadding;
double deltaW = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
double deltaH = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));

int width = map.getWidth()/2 - (int)(radius * deltaW);
int height = map.getHeight()/2 - (int)(radius * deltaH);

//Move current location marker to bottom of the map
Projection projection = map.getProjection();
GeoPoint centerPoint = (GeoPoint) projection.fromPixels(width, height);
mapController.setCenter(centerPoint);
```